# How to Retrieve Data form MySQL to Android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I need to create a login for my android app. I tried various guides and tutorials, but nothing resolved my problem. My code is the following.

Login.java:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

Button bLogin;
EditText etEmail, etPassword;
TextView tvRegisterLink;

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/sFitness/Login.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    tvRegisterLink =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);

    etEmail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    bLogin =(Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bLogin:
            loginUser();
            break;
        case R.id.tvRegisterLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
            break;
    }
}

private void loginUser() {
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    login(email, password);
}

private void login(final String email, final String password) {
    class LoginUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        LoginUserClass ruc = new LoginUserClass();


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            loading = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Please wait...", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

            data.put("email", params[0]);
            data.put("password", params[1]);

            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL, data);
            return result;

        }
    }
    LoginUser ru = new LoginUser();
    ru.execute(email, password);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Profile.class));
}
}
```

and LoginUserClass.java:

```
public class LoginUserClass {



public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                              HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

    URL url;
    String response = "";

    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();
        }
        else {
            response="Error Loading";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}

}
```

Login.php:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{

$email = $_POST["Email"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sfitness") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));

$sql= "SELECT Person.Nome FROM Person
    WHERE Person.Email='$email' AND Person.Password='$password'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($result){

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $name=$row["Nome"];
            echo "Successfully Login!".$name;

        }
        else{
            echo "Login failed, try again!"
        }


    }
    else{
        echo "Error, try again!";
    }


}
else{
    echo "Error!!";
}
```

What is the problem? If someone had a solution, please help me. The problem is that:

[image]

Comment: So, **What** is the problem?

Comment: You perhaps ought to edit the question and remove the php tag as this appears to be a java issue

Comment: what technique are you using in php please share code for php

Comment: the console show me these problems: **E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d2300** and **E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d5e10** @v.ladynev

Comment: @SilviaBerardo Please, add it to the question and is there any stacktrace?

Comment: I add the php Login file @valarmorghulis

Comment: @SilviaBerardo - Add the errors to the question also  please.

Comment: @SilviaBerardo there is nothing wrong with the php code, but how are you going to protect your api with the login you have

Comment: I don't know.. I don't know what is the problem and if I don't resolve it I can't modify the code to protec api and login. @valarmorghulis

Comment: nothing wrong with the logcat you posted,it's not related to your app or to the problem i mean no exceptions are there, so what is the problem? do you see the Toast on the screen? the toast located in `onPostexecute()` ? otherwise you need to find the stacktrace of the exception in logcat

Comment: I don't show the name of the user and any other datails about him. @Yazan the Toast in the **onPostExecute** doesn't show the name of the user who made the login and I need to show it.

Comment: what i was trying to say, you need to get a stacktrace of the error using logcat, the one you posted is NOT related to your app or to the problem it shows nothing useful to solve this problem.

Comment: This might not be the issue, but in your `PHP` you have `Nome` (`$row["Nome"];`) for a column name , should it be `Name` ?

Comment: check your apache error log file for php errors

Comment: No, "Nome" is correct because is italian @andre3wap